# How do I fix my "java.util.InputMismatchException" error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, mismatch

All I need it to do is loop again so the user can continuously use the program if they to. Let me know if there are any reference that I can read up to, to help me understand more about this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Module3Assignment1 {

    // public variables
    public static String letterChosen;
    public static int loop = 0;
    public static double radius, area;
    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // tells user what the program is about
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Round Object Calculator");
        System.out.println("This program will calculate the area of a circle of the colume of a sphere.");
        System.out.println("The calculations will be based on the user input radius.");
        System.out.println("");

            // loops while the user wants to calculate information
            while (loop == 0){

                Input();
                System.out.print(Answer());

                System.out.println("Do you want to calculate another round object (Y/N)? ");
                String input = scanner.next().toUpperCase();
                    if (input == "N"){
                        loop = 1;
                        }
            }

        // ending message/goodbye
        Goodbye();
        scanner.close();

    }

    private static void Input(){

        // prompts user for input
        System.out.print("Enter C for circle or S for sphere: ");
        letterChosen = scanner.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        System.out.print("Thank you. What is the radius of the circle (in inches): ");
        radius = scanner.nextDouble();

    }

    private static double AreaCircle(){

        // calculates the area of a circle
        area = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
        return area;

    }

    private static double AreaSphere(){

        // calculates the area of a sphere
        area = (4/3) * (Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3));
        return area;

    }

    private static String Answer(){

        //local variables
        String answer;

        if(letterChosen == "C"){
            // builds a string with the circle answer and sends it back
            answer = String.format("%s %f %s %.3f %s %n", "The volume of a circle with a radius of", radius, "inches is:", AreaCircle(), "inches");
            return answer;
        }else{
            // builds a string with the sphere answer and sends it back
            answer = String.format("%s %f %s %.3f %s %n", "The volume of a sphere with a radius of", radius, "inches is:", AreaSphere(), "cubic inches");
            return answer;
        }
    }

    private static String Goodbye(){

        // local variables
        String goodbye;

        // says and returns the goodbye message
        goodbye = String.format("%s", "Thank you for using the Round Object Calculator. Goodbye");
        return goodbye;
    }

}
```

The below is the console output and the error I am getting after execution

```
Welcome to the Round Object Calculator
This program will calculate the area of a circle of the colume of a sphere.
The calculations will be based on the user input radius.

Enter C for circle or S for sphere: C
Thank you. What is the radius of the circle (in inches): 12
The volume of a sphere with a radius of 12.000000 inches is: 5428.672 cubic inches 
Do you want to calculate another round object (Y/N)? 
Y
Enter C for circle or S for sphere: Thank you. What is the radius of the circle (in inches): C
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2387)
    at Module3Assignment1.Input(Module3Assignment1.java:48)
    at Module3Assignment1.main(Module3Assignment1.java:24)
```

Comment: Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html

Comment: What is **exactly** your problem? What happens? What do you **want** to happen? Can you provide example fo failure?

Comment: Kind of dangerous to include calls to `nextLine()` in with calls to `next()` or `nextDouble()` on the same Scanner.  I'd probably replace `nextLine()` with `next()` and see if that helps.  Your error actually means that your Scanner is encountering letters where it expects numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Module3Assignment1 {
// public static variables are discouraged... 
private static char letterChosen; //char takes less memory 
private static char useAgain = 'Y'; //just use the answer to loop... 
private static double radius, area;
private static String answer;
private  static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


//you might want to clear the screen after the user gave an answer to another round object
private static void clearScreen(){
    for(int i =0;i<50;i++){System.out.print("\n");}
}

public void input(){

    // prompts user for input
    System.out.print("Enter C for circle or S for sphere: ");
    letterChosen = scanner.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.print("Thank you. What is the radius of the circle (in inches): ");
    radius = scanner.nextDouble();
    this.answer= answer(letterChosen);

}

public double areaCircle(double radius){

    // calculates the area of a circle
    area = Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
    return area;

}

public double areaSphere(double radius){

    // calculates the area of a sphere
    area = (4/3) * (Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3));
    return area;

}

public String answer(char letterChosen){

    //local variables
    String answer = "";
    if(letterChosen=='c'||letterChosen=='C'){
        answer = String.format("%s %f %s %.3f %s %n", "The volume of a circle with a radius of", radius, "inches is:", areaCircle(radius), "inches");
    }else{
        answer = String.format("%s %f %s %.3f %s %n", "The volume of a sphere with a radius of", radius, "inches is:", areaSphere(radius), "cubic inches");
    }
    return answer;
}

private static String goodbye(){

    // local variables
    String goodbye;

    // says and returns the goodbye message
    goodbye = String.format("%s", "Thank you for using the Round Object Calculator. Goodbye");
    return goodbye;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // tells user what the program is about
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Round Object Calculator");
    System.out.println("This program will calculate the area of a circle of the colume of a sphere.");
    System.out.println("The calculations will be based on the user input radius.");
    System.out.println("");
    Module3Assignment1 ass1 = new Module3Assignment1();

        // loops while the user wants to calculate a round object
        while (useAgain == 'Y'||useAgain=='y'){

            ass1.input();
            System.out.print(answer);
            System.out.println("Do you want to calculate another round object (Y/N)? ");
            useAgain = scanner.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println(useAgain);
            clearScreen();
        }

    // ending message/goodbye
    System.out.println(goodbye());
    scanner.close();

}
```

}

Some things that I changed:

- I used **char** instead of **String**. **String** takes up **more memory** than **char**.
- added clearScreen() method which "clears" the screen when you're using console.
- I added a parameter radius to areaSphere and areaCircle methods. This makes the methods reusable.
- I changed all the public static variables to private static. using **public static variables** is **HIGHLY DISCOURAGED**. You may read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil) to find out why.
- and to prevent public static variables, I created an instance of Module3Assignment1 instead of having everything in static.
- changed the casing of method names. Please follow camel-casing, which means that the first letter of the method is lowercase and the other words will have the first letter in uppercase (e.g. input(), areaSphere() )

A comment about comparing Strings:

> **==** compares **REFERENCES TO THE OBJECT** , **NOT VALUES**

use **.equals()** or **.equalsIgnoreCase()** if you want to compare the values of two Strings. here is a sample syntax:

```
if(string1.equals(string2)){
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Concept One

Always use `.equals Method` while Comparing String in Java

So

```
if(letterChosen == "C")
```

Should be `if(letterChosen.equals("C"))` and so the Others

> Concept Two.

This might be one of the reason that is happening with your code . **You have  already taken a UserInput from the keyboard object of the scanner class that's why it's giving the else response. This particularly happens when you take other than String input from that object**

Thats because the Scanner#nextDouble method does not read the last newline character of your input, and thus that newline is consumed in the next call to Scanner#nextLine.

```
WorkAround Fire a blank Scanner#nextLine call after Scanner#nextDouble to consume newline.

Or Use Two Scanner Object.
```

Demo What Happens With Same Scanner Object for Both nextLine() and nextInt()

public class Test {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=keyboard.nextInt();

        String userResponse;
        while(true) {
            userResponse = keyboard.nextLine();
            if(userResponse.length() == 1 && userResponse.charAt(0) == 'y') {
                System.out.println("Great! Let's get started.");
                break;
            }
            else if(userResponse.length() == 1 && userResponse.charAt(0) == 'n') {
                System.out.println("Come back next time " + "" + ".");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid response.");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Output

```
5
Invalid response.
```

now change the code structure to get String Input from that scanner Object and not get another kind of data types the code works.

With String as previous Input

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
        String n=keyboard.nextLine();
        String userResponse;
        while(true) {
            userResponse = keyboard.nextLine();
            if(userResponse.length() == 1 && userResponse.charAt(0) == 'y') {
                System.out.println("Great! Let's get started.");
                break;
            }
            else if(userResponse.length() == 1 && userResponse.charAt(0) == 'n') {
                System.out.println("Come back next time " + "" + ".");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid response.");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Output

```
j
y
Great! Let's get started.
```

Without any previous response with that object your code will work.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);

        String userResponse;
        while(true) {
            userResponse = keyboard.nextLine();
            if(userResponse.length() == 1 && userResponse.charAt(0) == 'y') {
                System.out.println("Great! Let's get started.");
                break;
            }
            else if(userResponse.length() == 1 && userResponse.charAt(0) == 'n') {
                System.out.println("Come back next time " + "" + ".");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid response.");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and Gives me the desired output

```
y
Great! Let's get started.
```

I usually have been doing this whole time creating two OBJECT of Scanner Class one to get String Input and other to get other data types Input
(Too be frank even i have been not able to figure out why i needed to create two Object's for receiving String and Other data types in java without any error. If anyone know please let me know )

Comment: use next() and not nextLine()